# groupby and aggregate on the resulting groups

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have a dataframe with a column Status which values are either 'OPEN' or 'CLOSED'. I would like to do a `groupby()` on multiple columns and use the following rule for that Status column: *if there is one or more 'OPEN' values in the group then the aggregate should return 'OPEN' else 'CLOSED'*

I tried the following:

```
df_agg = df.groupby(['col1', 'col2', 'col3'], as_index=False)
           .agg({'col4': 'sum', 'Status': lambda x: np.where(x == 'OPEN', 'OPEN', 'CLOSED')}).reset_index(drop=True)
```

but this returns lists like ['OPEN', 'CLOSED'], ['OPEN', 'CLOSED', 'CLOSED'] and so on. Is there a better way using the `agg()` function to return a single value of 'OPEN' or 'CLOSED' rather than doing the `groupby()` and then doing again something like below?

```
np.where(df_agg['Status'].str.contains('OPEN'), 'OPEN', 'CLOSED')
```

Comment: The max of `"Open"` and `"Closed"` is?

Comment: Please [edit] to put a better title; see [ask] for tips on that. For example, [if I'm right and you just forgot to aggregate](/a/77566186/4518341), you might put something like "How do I check if there's at least one of some value in a column?"

Comment: It might also help to provide a [reproducible pandas example](/q/20109391/4518341), i.e. some example data, current output, and desired output.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Check if a pandas Series has at least one item greater than a value](/q/34148815/4518341). ("greater than" is basically the same as "equal to" since they're both comparisons.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible with `any` test if at least one match `OPEN` in lambda function:

```
#if need test substring OPEN
lambda x: 'OPEN' if x.str.contains('OPEN').any() else 'CLOSED'

#if need test string OPEN
lambda x: 'OPEN' if x.eq('OPEN').any() else 'CLOSED'
```

Better is test before groupby and because `OPEN > CLOSED` alpha numerically aggregate `max`:

```
#if need test substring OPEN
df_agg = (df.assign(Status = np.where(df['Status'].str.contains('OPEN'), 
                                      'OPEN', 'CLOSED'))
          .groupby(['col1', 'col2', 'col3'], as_index=False)
           .agg({'col4': 'sum', 'Status': 'max'}))

#if need test string OPEN
df_agg = (df.assign(Status = np.where(df['Status'].eq('OPEN'), 
                                      'OPEN', 'CLOSED'))
          .groupby(['col1', 'col2', 'col3'], as_index=False)
           .agg({'col4': 'sum', 'Status': 'max'}))
```

Or:

```
#if need test substring OPEN
df_agg = (df.assign(Status = df['Status'].str.contains('OPEN'))
           .groupby(['col1', 'col2', 'col3'], as_index=False)
           .agg({'col4': 'sum', 'Status': 'any'})
           .assign(Status = lambda x: x['Status'].map({True:'OPEN',False:'CLOSED'}))

#if need test string OPEN
df_agg = (df.assign(Status = df['Status'].eq('OPEN'))
           .groupby(['col1', 'col2', 'col3'], as_index=False)
           .agg({'col4': 'sum', 'Status': 'any'})
           .assign(Status = lambda x: x['Status'].map({True:'OPEN',False:'CLOSED'}))
```

Comment: Why are you using `df.loc[x.index, 'Status']` when that's equivalent to `x`? Why are you using `.str.contains()` when OP said the "values are either 'OPEN' or 'CLOSED' "? I mean why not just use `.eq()`? I posted [my own answer](/a/77566186/4518341) that I think is more to-the-point.

Answer (score 0):

You just forgot to aggregate, i.e. use [`.any()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.any.html):

```
np.where(x.eq('OPEN').any(), 'OPEN', 'CLOSED')
```

But this is a scalar so you don't really need `np.where`:

```
'OPEN' if x.eq('OPEN').any() else 'CLOSED'
```